# Shaft to swap direction of rotation

Tags: gears, mechanisms

What is the simplest way if you have a shaft rotating clockwise for it to have an extension that rotates anti clockwise. Least loss of energy is best so i think a mechanical mechanism would be best.

I am thinking is there a way you could use the main shaft in a turbo fan engine to drive another fan in the opposing direction in front of the original fan.

Comment: Do you mean simple to build, or simple to maintain, or simple to calculate?  Seems fairly straightforward to do with gears regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Least loss of energy would be using one gear with adequate lubrication.

I prefer planetary gears because they last much longer and distribute the load better. Plus you can do it with a hollow shaft. The center shaft turns clockwise, the planet gears turn counterclockwise as does the outer shaft.

Here is a link that should show you a gif of the gear in action.

https://giphy.com/gifs/yXQrz0IscQeWs

Comment: Why isn't this used in turbo fan engines to have a contrarotating fan?

Comment: They have used counter-rotating blades on aircraft (see link below) and steam turbines use fixed blades that fit between the moving blades that kind-of do the same thing by forcing the steam to hit the next set of turning blades at an angle that will impart the most kinetic energy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra-rotating_propellers